# How to delete substring in C

Tags: c, string

How can I delete a string inside another string in **C**?

```
 const char *   Cmd = start;more;muchmore;123 45;rest
```

Now I want to remove the `"123 45;"` from `Cmd`.

The `"123"` can be used to identify the start and semicolon after `45` as end.

So after this operation the `Cmd` should be `start;more;muchmore;rest`

Comment: and what did you try so far? how that failed?

Answer (score 3):

> So after this operation the `Cmd` should be `start;more;muchmore;rest`

Acutally with the declaration what you have right now you can't.

```
const char *   Cmd = start;more;muchmore;123 45;rest  // missing "" in this
```

`Cmd` is declared `const` so anything like `Cmd[0]='A';` can't be done .

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty untested non error checking code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char Cmd[] = "start;more;muchmore;123 45;rest";
    char toberemoved[] = "123 45;";

    /* get pointer to start of string to be removed*/
    char *start = strstr(Cmd, toberemoved);

    /* get pointer to end of string to be removed*/
    char *end = start + strlen(toberemoved);

    /* move rest of string to former start of string to be removed*/
    memmove(start, start + strlen(toberemoved), strlen(end) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fish. I'll come back tomorrow for another. Make sure to have it ready!

Answer (score 1):

like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *proc(const char *cmd, const char *id){//id : start with id
    char *str = strdup(cmd);//make copy
    char *to, *from;
    size_t id_len = strlen(id);

    to = from = str;
    while(*from){
        if(strncmp(from, id, id_len)==0){
            while(*from && *from++ != ';'); //skip upto ;
        } else {
            while((*to = *from) && (++to, *from++ != ';'));//copy upto ;
        }
    }
    *to = '\0';

    return str;
}

int main(void){
    const char *Cmd = "start;more;muchmore;123 45;rest";

    Cmd = proc(Cmd, "123");
    puts(Cmd);
    free((void*)Cmd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile i solved it like this. Not nice but i works :-)

```
    int laengeGesamt = strlen(Cmd );

    char *rest = strstr(Cmd , "123");
    char tempRest[100];
    strcpy (tempRest, rest);
    int laengeRest = strlen(tempRest);

    int laengeNeed = laengeGesamt - laengeRest;

    char need[100];
    strncpy(need,Cmd ,laengeNeed);
    need[laengeNeed]='\0'; 

    strcat(need,"rest"); 

    Cmd = need;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jabberwocky's answer but you can use "strcpy" for the last step.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main(void)
{
    char Cmd[] = "start;more;muchmore;123 45;rest";
    char removed[] = "123 45;";

    /* get pointer to start of string to be removed*/
    char *start = strstr(Cmd, removed);

    /* get pointer to end of string to be removed*/
    char *end = start + strlen(removed);

    /* remove string "123 45;" from Cmd */
    strcpy(start, end);

    /* will print: start;more;muchmore;rest */
    printf("%s\n", Cmd);
}
```

What happened with `strcpy(start, end)`?

`strcpy(start, end)` will copy `end` to the address `start` points to, in this case, `start` points to '1' in Cmd, while `end` points to 'r'(first char of rest).

So `strcpy(start, end)` will copy `"rest\0"` (`'\0'` is the string terminator) to where `"123 45;rest"` was. Then `start` will become `"rest"` and as a result, `Cmd` will become `"start;more;muchmore;rest"`.